# How to load all non-digit letters of a particular language, let's say Russian?

Tags: python, string, nlp

So, a function is returning some garbage as text output, and all the characters in that output are in Russian Cyrillic. To avoid this, I need to do some checks, for which a list of all characters in Russian Cyrillic is required.

Now, the question is can I generalize this to any given language? Given a language, can I get a list of all its characters?

Comment: Your question doesn't align with the heading. Please explain what you mean by "non-digit strings"

Comment: @CtrlZ Fixed. I meant, all the letters of a given language, as in by English, I should have 'A-Z' which we can do using string.ascii_uppercase method. I'm looking for a similar approach in other language.

Comment: I guess you don't want to do it manually right as you would have to do it for any arbitrary character collection. like `foo = set("abc")`.

Comment: Not really, no. If you know the script, you can extract characters in that script only using Unicode properties; but this does not properly map to a specific language. If the script is Cyrillic, you would get the characters of Russian but also any other characters in that script which are only used in other languages which use that script, like Ukrainian or Kazakh etc. Closer to home, Latin script would include the Danish/Norwegian æ/ø, Swedish/Finnish/German ä/ö, French œ/é/è/ç etc, Portuguese õ/ã, Spanish ñ etc etc etc.

Comment: @JonSG Yes, for now, I'm doing it manually. I'm looking for an easier method.

Comment: Perhaps a more fruitful approach would be to build a trigram model of the language you want to capture; this works well on longer passages of text but tends to accept a lot of noise if the pieces of text you want to target are short.

Comment: A human can discern that _"Schwartz y Babaoglu ganan el Nobel"_ is probably Spanish even with the foreign names, but a simple statistical model will obviously struggle.

Comment: For a limited scenario where the output is either Russian or random computer garbage, of course, simply selecting sequences of Cyrillics is almost certainly good enough. For Chinese, for example, what works also depends on the encoding; random bytes tend to look superficially like Chinese in UTF-16.

Comment: I am kind of surprised there is not even a 3rd party [string module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) for Russian.

Comment: @JonSG You should look upon that as an opportunity

Comment: @CtrlZ It would be if I even knew what the valid Russian code points where (which I don't)  :-(

Comment: I think the answer to this question is that it's not possible to generalise for any language. You'd need to decide on which alphabets you're interested in. Indeed, some languages (e.g. Mandarin) don't have an alphabet *per se*